# fancy-regex not returning all matches in the input

Tags: regex, rust

I'm trying to get all the matches from the input where there are two matches for the given regular expression currently, but for some reason I only get the first match. I've tried to define global flag but it looks like it's not working (I guess it should do a global search by default). [Here](http://regexr.com/572pm) is a proof that regex works.

```
use fancy_regex::Regex;

let input = String::from("{#test1} {#test2}");
let re = Regex::new("(?<={#)(.*?)(?=})").unwrap();

let input_string_slice = &input.clone();
let result = re.captures(input_string_slice);

let captures = result.expect("Error during regex parsing").expect("No match found");
let first_match = captures.get(1).expect("No group");
let second_match = captures.get(2).expect("No group"); // panics
println!("{} {}", first_match.as_str(), second_match.as_str());
```

I'm using [`fancy-regex`](https://crates.io/crates/fancy-regex) crate 0.3.5.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there's a bug in a library involved, so you'd better file an issue at their github.

```rust
// prints     Captures(Fancy { text: "{#test1} {#test2}", saves: [2, 7, 2, 7] })
// instead of Captures(Fancy { .., saves [2, 7, 11, 16] }
println!("{:?}", captures);

// prints     ["test1", "test1"]
// instead of ["test1", "test2"]
println!(
    "{:?}",
    captures
        .iter()
        .map(|x| x.map_or("", |x| x.as_str()))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
);
```